# Warning message not shown by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have JQuery weather , and his also completed , but i have problem some code not showing data . in the last JQuery code called message , when the temp weather be higher show message to the user , example : if temp weather 48C show message :  it's feels very how weather be careful . but the message not showing .

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["q"].value;
    console.log('query string=' + x);
    if (x==null || x=="")
        var error = "Empty query, Please enter a query.";
    else if(/\d/.test(x)) {
        var regUKPostcode = /^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ])([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$/;
        var regUSCANZipcode = /(^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$)/;
        var regLatLong = /^(-?(90|(\d|[1-8]\d)(\.\d{1,6}){0,1}))\,{1}(-?(180|(\d|\d\d|1[0-7]\d)(\.\d{1,6}){0,1}))$/;
        var validIP = function(ip) {
            var values = ip.split('.');
            if(values.length != 4) return false;

            for(var v in values)
                if(values[v] < 0 || values[v] > 255) return false;

            return true;
        };

        if(validIP(x)) {
            updateDom(x);
            return false;
        } else if(regUSCANZipcode.test(x)) {
            updateDom(x);
            return false;
        } else if(regUKPostcode.test(x)) {
            updateDom(x);
            return false;
        } else if(regLatLong.test(x)) {
            updateDom(x);
            return false;
        } else
            error = "Please enter an valid US/UK/Canada Postal Code or IP or (Lat,Long) query.";
    } else {
        updateDom(x);
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = error;
    return false;
};

function updateDom(q) {
    getLocalWeather(q, function(result) {
        document.getElementById('weatherData').innerHTML = result;
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "";
    });

    return false;
}

function errorView(error) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = error;
}

function resultView(jsonres) {
   var template = '<div id="information" style="background-color:white;border-radius: 10px; position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 400px; margin-right: 180px;margin-top: 200px;opacity: 300;"><div id="information" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.73); position: absolute; width: 700px; height: 50px;top: 0px;opacity: 300;"><h1 style="font-size:25px;float: right;position: relative;right: 20px;color: white;">36 ساعة القادمة</h1></div><div id="weather"style="position: absolute;top: 75;margin-right: 10;width: 650;"><div style="color:#07CFFC;float: left;"><%= date %>|<%= location %>\</div><br><br><div id="weathericon"style="float: left;"><div id="temp"style="float: right;font-size: 45px;"><%= temp %>&nbsp;</div><img src="<%= icon %>" alt="Weather Condition" /></div>\
     <div id"weatherDesc" style="color:#1707FC;float: right;font-size: 25px;top: 55px;  position: absolute;font-weight: bold;"><%= weatherDesc %> | الشعور الحقيقي  <%= FeelsLikeC %></div><br><br><br>\
     <div id"humidity" style="color:#1707FC;float: right;font-size: 25px;  font-weight: bold;  ">الرطوبة : <%= humidity %> <img src="http://www.calibrationservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/icon-humidity-body-effects.png"style="height: 45;  position: relative;top: 10;"></div><br><br><br><br><br>\
     <li>Min Temperature: <b><%= tempMinC %>\u2103</b></li>\
     <li>Cloud Cover: <b><%= cloudcover %></b></li>\
     <li>Humidity: <b><%= humidity %></b></li>\
     <li>Observation Time: <b><%= observation_time %></b></li>\
     <li>Precipitation: <b><%= precipMM %>MM</b></li>\
     <li>Pressure: <b><%= pressure %></b></li>\
     <li>Visibility: <b><%= visibility %></b></li>\
     <li>Wind Direction 16Point: <b><%= winddir16Point %></b></li>\
     <li>Wind Direction Degree: <b><%= winddirDegree %></b></li>\
<div id="moonrise"><%= winddirDegree %></div></div>';


    var vars = 
    {
        location: jsonres.data.request[0].query,
        date: jsonres.data.weather[0].date,
        FeelsLikeC: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].FeelsLikeC,  
        temp: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C,
        weatherDesc: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].lang_ar[0].value,
        humidity: jsonres.data.weather[0].humidity,
        tempMinC: jsonres.data.weather[0].tempMinC,
        cloudcover: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].cloudcover,
        humidity: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].humidity,
        observation_time: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].observation_time,
        precipMM: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].precipMM,
        pressure: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].pressure,
        visibility: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].visibility,
        winddir16Point: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].winddir16Point,
        winddirDegree: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].winddirDegree,
        windspeed: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].windspeedKmph,
        icon: jsonres.data.current_condition[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value,
        moonrise: jsonres.data.weather[0].hourly[0].maxtempC,
  

    };

        return _.template(template, vars);

}

function getLocalWeather(q, onResult) {
  var baseurl = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx";
  $.getJSON(baseurl + '?callback=?&lang=ar&&mca=mca&3Dno&fx24=fx24&3Dyes&includelocation=includeLocation&3Dyes&', {
    q: q,
    num_of_days: '5',
    format: 'json',
    key: '024f29167186fbffaba266b329c181e9dac4d6c7'
  })
  .done(function( jsonres ) {
      console.log('getJSON'+JSON.stringify(jsonres));
      if(jsonres.data.hasOwnProperty('error'))
          errorView(jsonres.data.error[0].msg); 
      else onResult(resultView(jsonres));
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
          errorView("Request Failed: " + err);
    
var temp =(jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
             
if (temp < 46) {
    $('#message').html("it's feels cold, get a jacket");
} else if (temp < 53) {
    $('#message').html("it's feels normal");
} else {
    $('#message').html("it's feels hot, switch on your AC");
}

   
  });
  
}
```

```html
   <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
   City or town name; IP address; US or Canada Postal Code or US Zipcode; (Latitude,longitude): <input type="text" name="q">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
   <div style="color:#B20528"><span id="status"></span></div>
   <div id="weatherData"></div>
      <div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried alerting the `temp` value to see if it is defined?

Comment: The message is not at all showing or it is not showing the correct content you want. please check your "if condition" you have used if(temp<53){ twice with different content.

Comment: i checked and make different but still same

Comment: As per the comment in my answer, temp is "48C". The conditions will never met.

Answer (score 0):

First, your last two conditions are the same, I believe they should be:

```
if (temp < 48) {
    $('#message').html("it's feels cold, get a jacket");
} else if (temp < 53) {
    $('#message').html("it's feels normal");
} else {
    $('#message').html("it's feels hot, switch on your AC");
}
```

second, what is `temp` holding? Is it a number? or is it something like `"48C"` Because if it is a string your conditions will never be fulfilled.

If you get a string, you should do:

```
var temp = parseInt(jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
```

Always assuming that `jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C)` begins with the number followed by the temperature type.

## EDIT

As per your last comment, seems that your element has actually and id and not a class, so it shoult be `$('#message')` instead of `$('.message')`

## EDIT Nº2

As per the update on your question:

```
var temp =(jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
```

Will not be a number ever, the parenthesis are making it a condition, so it will be a boolean value, should be:

```
var temp = parseInt(jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C);
```

Or:

```
var temp = jsonres.data.current_condition[0].temp_C;
```

Comment: You conditions will never met... 48C < 48 will always be false. Remove the "C" from your temp in order to be able to check the conditions. Check the rest of my answer where I wrote about parseInt.

Comment: i delete c and rest but still same

Comment: How are you running the code? document ready? any error in your console?

Comment: after deleting C, use parseInt anyway to ensure that the variable is converted to a number.

Comment: what does console.log(temp); output? and console.log(typeof temp);

Comment: now error i have just empty       <div id="message"></div>

Comment: Check my edit. You are trying to replace the html of an element with class message, but you actually have an element with ID message.

Comment: Can you explain more or give me example

Comment: Check the code in my answer with the conditions, they are updated.

Comment: Replace $('.message') with $('#message')

Comment: its same not thing yet :(

Comment: You will have to update your question with the full code including your HTML markup.

Comment: Edited my answer again.

Comment: its same , :( am sorry

Answer (score -1):

Try using [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('.message').append("it's feels cold, get a jacket");
```

Comment: How would this solve the issues? Append and html are basically the same, the difference is that html replaces the content and append adds it to the end of it.

Comment: @taxicala That is true. I was just suggesting an alternate way of putting stuff on the page. I usually use append, and it usually works for me.

Comment: What if the OP is using an event? each time the event is triggered, it will append a new message to the element. It's better to clear the content. Either use .empty() before .append() or .html().